# Grunt target subdirectories only

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is it possible with Grunt to target only subdirectories? I have a javascript folder in my project and it contains a few .js files and within this folder I also have a few subdirectories.

```
MainDirectory
    /javascript
        global.js
        modal.js
        /subdirectory1
            somescripts.js
        /subdirectory2
            otherscrips.js
```

So in my grunt config I am using concat to grab only the files in the javascript folder and ignore the subdirectories. So what I need is to copy the files in the subdirectory and ignore the files outside the subdirectory, in this case global.js and modal.js. Here is my copy code (Gruntfile.js):

```
copy: {
  subdirs: {
    expand: true,
    dot: true,
    cwd: 'javascript',
    dest: 'app/assets/javascript',
    src: '**/*.js'// I know this grabs files and subdirectories
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this but after Googling and reading Grunt docs I still cant figure out a proper solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `src: ['**/*.js', '!*.js']`? reference: [grunt globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach would be to specify all files in the current and any subdirectories, then explicitly ignore all files in the current directory.

reference [grunt globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

Change your `src` property to:

```
src: ['**/*.js', '!*.js'],
```